# Cypher Query Complexity

Tags: neo4j, cypher, time-complexity

How do I find out the complexity of Cypher queries?

This is my query:

```
MATCH (G1:FirstGraph) 
MATCH (G2:SecondGraph {IdRule:G1.IdRule}) 
WHERE G2.VRule<>G1.VRule  
MATCH (R:Rule{IdRule:G1.IdRule}) 
WITH G1,G2, count(R) as NbrOfVers
MATCH (T:ResultNode)
WITH T,sum(1-(tofloat(ABS(G2.VRule-G1.VRule))/NbrOfVers)) AS sum
SET T.SubCorrel = sum
```

Comment: What do you mean with complexity?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_of_algorithms

Comment: I supposed that you refer to algo complexity but doesn't make sense in this case since it depends from the choose of the query optimiser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way of determining the "cost" of a Cypher query is to precede your query using the [PROFILE](http://neo4j.com/docs/2.3.0/how-do-i-profile-a-query.html) keyword. The profile output gives you the steps that the DB took to execute your query, and it will also tell you how many DB hits it took.

In general, you want to try to minimize the number of DB hits, as they are relatively expensive.

*It would be nice if `PROFILE` (and `EXPLAIN`) could output the [computational complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_complexity_theory) of a query in [big O notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation), but that is not currently done.*

Comment: I tried Profile. It is interesting. But how to give a sense of the number of hits to mesure the performance of the query?

Comment: The profile output gives you the number of hits per step, and the total number of hits.

Comment: Thank you; but when we can say that the query is poor or good. How can i interpret the number of hits?

Comment: Right now, it is kind of an art to figure out how to interpret the profile results. If we could get neo4j to provide Big O notation in profiling results, then it should be obvious.

Comment: There is documentation on some of the [operators you can find in a profile](http://neo4j.com/docs/2.3.0/execution-plans.html).

Comment: Thank you very muche for your help